# How to get data from website/url in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

The topic is Reading data from website. As an example i have taken reviews data of messenger app with url - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca&hl=en. I am trying to use beautifulsoup and request module. Could someone please suggest me the right way to do so as I am a beginner and just started learning this topic in Python 3.

Comment: When i tried --------import requests, bs4
url="https://learn.upgrad.com/v/course/258/session/30789/segment/162338"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.txt, "html5lib")
reviews = soup.select('.review-body')
print(type(reviews))
print(len(reviews))
print("\n")

Comment: Welcome to SO! First of all, your profile name is your email. That might be unintentional. Secondly, I recommend posting your code inside the question itself.